# Errors when trying to install 'semPlot' R package

Tags: r, semplot

I'm trying to install the package 'semPlot' in RStudio, and keep getting errors:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rockchalk' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL 'zip' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rockchalk'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rockchalk’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/00LOCK-OpenMx'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenMx’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'rockchalk', 'OpenMx' are not available for package 'semPlot'
* removing 'C:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/semPlot'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘semPlot’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpE9qK0s\downloaded_packages’
```

I already installed the package ‘rockchalk’, but it didn't help.
The first time I tried to install 'semPlot' there was an almost endless process which also ended with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `install_github` function to install R packages hosted on GitHub from the `devtools` package. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
devtools::install_github('SachaEpskamp/semPlot')
library(semPlot)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I still get plenty of errors: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'downlit':
Load failed in loadNamespace() for 'downlit', details:
call: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
DLL 'cachem' not found: not installed for architecture?
Error: loading failed
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'Error: package or namespace load failed for 'roxygen2'
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
ERROR: dependencies 'gert', 'gh' are not available for 'usethis'
ERROR: dependencies 'usethis', 'pkgdown', 'roxygen2', 'rversions' not available for 'devtools'
‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Hi @Aya, Have you tried installing the `downlit`, `roxygen2` packages?

Comment: I think I tried installing roxigen2. Anyway, after uninstalling R and Rstudio, then re-installing and solving some small problem with tidyverse, I finally managed to install semPlot. Thank you for trying to help @Quinten!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling R and RStudio, and then installing them, and googling a small problem that came up with tydiverse.